# Concept Formation

Tags: plato, philosophy-of-logic, concept

I would like some suggestions about [Concept Formation](https://www.britannica.com/topic/concept-formation). Especially if there is a reference to Plato's Theory of Forms. I believe the two are linked but cannot find appropriate material. Thank you.

Comment: See [Innateness and Contemporary Theories of Cognition](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/innateness-cognition/) as well as [The Historical Controversies Surrounding Innateness](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/innateness-history/).

Comment: Look at the book [Forms and Concepts: Concept Formation in the Platonic Tradition by Christoph Helmig](https://books.google.com/books/about/Forms_and_Concepts.html?id=ELTMRpaMNYoC), here is a [review](https://www.hse.ru/mirror/pubs/lib/data/access/ram/ticket/50/1537898095336a42ed93623119ca7ff26536373c77/rev%20Helming,%20Forms%20and%20Concepts.pdf). There is also a book of essays [Platonic Ideas and Concept Formation](https://books.google.com/books?id=8YkN4q5IUSMC&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*

You can consider the "classical" theory of *concept*, from Plato to [Frege](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/).

See ["On Concept and Object" (originally published as "Ueber Begriff und Gegenstand" (1892))](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2251430.pdf) : the application of a concept can be completely specified by discovering a set of necessary and sufficient conditions that define the objects falling under the concept. These conditions constitute the analysis of the concept (according to grammar : its definition).

And you can compare it with [Ludwig Wittgenstein](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/)'s account, exposed into his [Philosophical Investigations (published posthumously, in 1953)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Investigations), of [family resemblance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_resemblance) of concepts.

See also [Language game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_game_(philosophy)).

And see Joachim Schulte, *Concept Formation*, into Nuno Venturinha (editor), [Wittgenstein after his Nachlass](https://books.google.it/books?id=-p6HDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Palgrave (2010), page 128-on.